# Networking problems using free version of ProtonVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, split-tunnel

I am using the free version of ProtonVPN on my Windows 10 Laptop. I connect the laptop to the internet using Wifi from Cable Internet.

My ProtonVPN is configured for split tunneling - Only the Brave Browser on my laptop is to use the VPN & all other applications would be excluded from the VPN tunnel.

[image: Proton VPN Settings]

I have 2 problems

1. My problem is that my native connection (the one that is used by the other browsers) behaves differently when my VPN tunnel is on. This is an occasional problem doesn't happen all time. I am unable to reach several sites on my other browsers (unable to connect to the site). If I shut down the VPN, the same sites now start opening through my excluded browsers. Sometimes just shutting down the VPN works, sometimes, I also need to run "ipconfig /renew" before it starts working - even this is not foolproof, sometimes it just doesn't work for a long time.
2. When I startup my ProtonVPN, while it's connecting to the VPN server & tunneling my laptop has now internet connection till the time it's done establishing the tunnel. No other browser (the ones excluded from the VPN) can connect to anything till then.

The 2nd issue is not a big one (it's just for a few seconds usually), I mentioned it just in can help in trouble shooting the issue. But the 1st one is almost making me consider giving up using VPN at all.

Are there any solutions for this?

Comment: Maybe not a solution, but have you added an IP address in this window?

Comment: @pbies - What do you mean "added an IP address in this window"?

Comment: You have IP addresses in the lower right corner.

Comment: @pbies - Lower right hand corner of which window?

Comment: The one you have given screenshot of.

Comment: @pbies - No, I haven't added any IP Address there.

Comment: Does adding IP address help?

Comment: @pbies - What IP Address should I add? I mainly want to use VPN for just one site. However, the site points to different IP addresses based on location, load & other stuff.

Comment: Your computer's IP address.

Comment: @pbies - as per the docs https://protonvpn.com/support/protonvpn-split-tunneling/ - you add the IP address of the site you don't want going through the tunnel in that window (or only want going through the tunnel). So how would adding my own IP address help? Also I am on DHCP.

Comment: Then it is only for the site. Not your IP address. No need to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

According to many reports, split tunneling on ProtonVPN is very buggy
and has been so since this feature was introduced in 2018.

Some example posts:

- [Does anyone else have problems with Split Tunneling?](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProtonVPN/comments/by5cxr/does_anyone_else_have_problems_with_split/)
- [Split tunneling not working with online gaming](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProtonVPN/comments/d47jyx/split_tunneling_not_working_with_online_gaming/)
- [Split tunneling on windows 10](https://protonvpn.com/support/protonvpn-split-tunneling/)

According to the reports, the technical implementation of ProtonVPN
weirdly works for some applications but fails in several ways for others.
I have seen reports where regressions in ProtonVPN were fixed by
downgrading to a previous version (not recommended), and others
where the poster fixed the problem by switching to another VPN product
(such as ExpressVPN).

The original 2018
[announcement](https://protonvpn.com/support/protonvpn-split-tunneling/)
by ProtonVPN of split tunneling said:

> Since this feature is new to our services, feel free to report any bugs and issues that you encounter to our support team [here](https://protonvpn.com/support-form).

That's about all that you can do: File a bug report with the
ProtonVPN team, and if the answer is unsatisfactory then switch to
another product.

(The people that answer on this site don't have the ability to
fix bugs in ProtonVPN.)